# Error while connecting to Redshift from ETL Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

Created a connection to redshift cluster for AWS Glue and when tested it display following result

[image]

Do help me how to solve this?

updating question with connection settings,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you give us the connection configuration? In addition can you in future upload your pictures in a higher resolution? It's barely readable.

Comment: updated the question with connection configuration, redshift endpoint was provided correctly

Comment: Did you create S3 endpoint in your VPC or nat gateway?

Comment: Yes, S3 endpoint in VPC was created with endpoint type as interface

Comment: The error msg indicates that there is something wrong with your S3 endpoint. Have you setup its security groups? Can you verify from a private instance if you can access s3?

Comment: Security groups inbound rules are correct, I can access s3 from private instance. I have another ETL job which reads from S3 and writes to S3 that works fine. Connecting to Redshift is what causing this error